# how to fixup line breaks?

Tags: commands, whitespace

I'm looking for a command that behaves similiar to `fixup-whitespace`, but I want it to also remove line breaks between objects around point.

Comment: Does `delete-indentation` do what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but it only deletes one empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but this is more or less what I was looking for

```
(defun fixup-line-breaks ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pos (point)))
    (delete-region
     (progn
       (skip-chars-forward "[^\s\t\n]")
       (constrain-to-field nil pos t))
     (progn
       (re-search-backward "[^\s\t\n]")
       (forward-char)
       (constrain-to-field nil pos)))
    (insert "\n")
    (indent-for-tab-command)))
```